# Item added to collection gets removed on the client, but still exists on the server

Tags: meteor

I have created a collection that I call Graph, this is the server code:

```
Graphs = new Meteor.Collection("graphs");
Meteor.publish("graphs", function(){
    return Graphs.find();
} );
```

On the client I try to store things in this Graphs by:

```
Graphs = new Meteor.Collection("graphs");
Graphs.insert(graph);
```

And I see that it is inserted in the server side db by using meteor mongo:

```
db.graphs.count()
```

That returns '1'

In the client I also have this code to listen on changes:

```
Graphs.find().observe({
    added: function(graph) {
        console.log("added graph");
    }, 
    removed: function(graph) {  //removed gets called!
        console.log("removed graph");
    },
    changed: function(graph) {
        console.log("changed graph");
    }
});
```

But here it's get interesting, the output is 'added graph' immediately followed by 'removed graph'.

Why is it that I get the Graph inserted and communicated to the server, but in the client, it gets added and then removed?

Subsequent calls to Graphs.findOne() return "undefined" like it's still empty!?!
Any Ideas on where to look for more clues?

Edit:

If I put a break point in the "remove" above I get the following stack trace:

Graphs.find.observe.removed (graphwiki.js?a150874e1ce3cd4a32d7db02a03cff5239d1ae6e:548)
cursor.observeChanges.removed (minimongo.js?daa88dc39d67b40b11d6d6809d72361f9ef6a760:909)
(anonymous function) (minimongo.js?daa88dc39d67b40b11d6d6809d72361f9ef6a760:275)
_.extend.runTask (fiber_stubs_client.js?52687e0196bc1d3184ae5ea434a8859275702d94:30)
_.extend.flush (fiber_stubs_client.js?52687e0196bc1d3184ae5ea434a8859275702d94:58)
_.extend.drain (fiber_stubs_client.js?52687e0196bc1d3184ae5ea434a8859275702d94:66)
LocalCollection.remove (minimongo.js?daa88dc39d67b40b11d6d6809d72361f9ef6a760:500)
self._connection.registerStore.update (collection.js?682caa185350aa26968d4ffc274579a33922f0e6:109)
store.(anonymous function) (livedata_connection.js?5d09753571656c685bb10c7970eebfbf23d35ef8:404)
_.each.self._updatesForUnknownStores.(anonymous function) (livedata_connection.js?5d09753571656c685bb10c7970eebfbf23d35ef8:984)
*.each.*.forEach (underscore.js?ed2d2b960c0e746b3e4f9282d5de66ef7b1a2b4d:78)
(anonymous function) (livedata_connection.js?5d09753571656c685bb10c7970eebfbf23d35ef8:983)
*.each.*.forEach (underscore.js?ed2d2b960c0e746b3e4f9282d5de66ef7b1a2b4d:86)
_.extend._livedata_data (livedata_connection.js?5d09753571656c685bb10c7970eebfbf23d35ef8:980)
onMessage (livedata_connection.js?5d09753571656c685bb10c7970eebfbf23d35ef8:208)
(anonymous function) (stream_client_sockjs.js?6ef3fd3e8e39c1c357993f6936512726288ad127:179)
*.each.*.forEach (underscore.js?ed2d2b960c0e746b3e4f9282d5de66ef7b1a2b4d:78)
self.socket.onmessage (stream_client_sockjs.js?6ef3fd3e8e39c1c357993f6936512726288ad127:178)
REventTarget.dispatchEvent (sockjs-0.3.4.js?6f1db89d6b451d0faf6b7103782d92527931e66a:86)
SockJS._dispatchMessage (sockjs-0.3.4.js?6f1db89d6b451d0faf6b7103782d92527931e66a:1039)
SockJS._didMessage (sockjs-0.3.4.js?6f1db89d6b451d0faf6b7103782d92527931e66a:1097)
that.ws.onmessage (sockjs-0.3.4.js?6f1db89d6b451d0faf6b7103782d92527931e66a:1238)

Does this giv any hint on what may be wrong?

I can do insert in other collections at the same time that don't get rolebacked!
/Hans

Comment: Your description sounds like the change gets rejected by the server. Does the count on server increase each time you execute insert on client?  Do you have a `Graphs.allow()` rule on the server that give the client permission to insert?

Comment: Thanks!

I have no restriction on the access at all in my application, and other collection works. But I added a Graphs.allow() on the server that returns true in all cases, and there's no change.

The count increses on the server database, so the inserts is run allright. They are just never reflected in the client, because of the "remove" call. 

Added a stack trace if that could help anyone to give me more hints on where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side, do you subscribe to "graphs"? I think the client will otherwise remove it from its local collection since the document shouldn't be in the collection according to any subscription.

> Subsequent calls to Graphs.find() return "undefined" like it's still
>   empty!?!

I do find this odd. Doesn't Collection.find() always return a cursor?

Comment: And I meant Graphs.findOne() returns "undefined" not find() that I mistakenly wrote. Corrected now.